# Copying an XML node from a document to another document using Java DOM Parser

Tags: java, dom, xml-parsing

I have been implementing a simple algorithm that parses an XML file and resort its nodes based on an attribute value in node . I retrieve all nodes  and insert the whole  node to a sorted ArrayList. Then I created a new XML document and created new  and  tags but when I try to copy sorted Node  and append it to , an exception stating that  is still used in another document. I am using

```
Node sortedCnode= cNode.cloneNode(false); //tried true as well
b.appendChild(sortedCnode);
```

I think my code is trying to append the whole true. But, I don't know the proper way to do it

The XML looks like below

```
<A>
  <B>
    <C>
      <D>
      </D>
      <E>
      </E>
    </C>
  </B>
</A>
```

Comment: Can you give a sample xml with the attribute value based on which you prefer to sort?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out

to copy a node from source DOM to target DOM below should be used

```
targetBNode.appendChild(targetDOC.adoptNode(sourceCnode.cloneNode(true)));
```

Comment: I think the best approach here is to use xslt transformation rather than reading and re-creating the xml.

Answer (score 2):

A more complete answer is available here from Jherico: [How do I copy DOM nodes from one document to another in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/873247/how-do-i-copy-dom-nodes-from-one-document-to-another-in-java).

To summarize, you need to:

1. Copy the node
2. Import the copy into the destination document
3. Position the copy in the new document

Jherico provides two methods, one using cloneNode() and adoptNode() which is the same as the accepted answer. However, a shortcut method exists by using importNode() on Document which performs both of those operations for you.

```
targetBNode.appendChild(targetDOC.importNode(sourceCnode, true));
```