# Adding sub-element to element java (DOM)

Tags: java, xml, dom, element

Essentially, i'm creating an XML document from a file (a database), and then i'm comparing another parsed XML file (with updated information) to the original database, then writing the new information into the database.

I'm using java's org.w3c.dom.

After lots of struggling, i decided to just create a new Document object and will write from there from the oldDocument and newDocument ones i'm comparing the elements in.

The XML doc is in the following format:

```
<Log>
   <File name="something.c">
      <Warning file="something.c" line="101" column="23"/>
      <Warning file="something.c" line="505" column="71" />
   </File>
</Log>
```

as an example.

How would i go about adding in a new "warning" Element to the "File" without getting the pesky "org.w3c.dom.DOMException: WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR: A node is used in a different document than the one that created it." exception?

Cutting it down, I have something similar to:

```
public static Document update(Element databaseRoot, Element newRoot){
    Document doc = db.newDocument(); // DocumentBuilder defined previously

    Element baseRoot = doc.createElement("Log");

    //for each file i have:
    Element newFileRoot = doc.createElement("File");

    //some for loop that parses through each 'file' and looks at the warnings

    //when i come to a new warning to add to the Document:
    NodeList newWarnings = newFileToCompare.getChildNodes(); //newFileToCompare comes from the newRoot element

    for (int m = 0; m < newWarnings.getLength(); m++){

       if(newWarnings.item(m).getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
          Element newWarning = (Element)newWarnings.item(m);

          Element newWarningRoot = (Element)newWarning.cloneNode(false);
          newFileRoot.appendChild(doc.importNode(newWarningRoot,true)); // this is what crashes
       }
    }

    // for new files i have this which works:
    newFileRoot = (Element)newFiles.item(i).cloneNode(true);
    baseRoot.appendChild(doc.importNode(newFileRoot,true));

    doc.appendChild(baseRoot);
    return doc;
}
```

Any ideas? I'm beating my head against the wall. First time doing this.

Comment: do you tried the adoptElement method ? see this post it seem like yours : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/873247/how-do-i-copy-dom-nodes-from-one-document-to-another-in-java

Comment: @fabient If you look at the code that's what i'm doing... and it doesn't work. The newFileRoot is doc.getDocumentElement(). Also adoptElement doesn't exist.

Comment: Yes in Java it's imporNode (sorry method name change from javascript) method instead. In fact you cannot take a tree of Dom element, and put them in a new Dom Document. You need to import those nodes in the new document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going through with a debugger I verified that the document owners were correct. Using node.getOwnerDocument(), I realized that the newFileRoot was connected to the wrong document earlier when I created it, so I changed

```
Element newFileRoot = (Element)pastFileToFind.cloneNode(false);
```

to

```
Element newFileRoot = (Element)doc.importNode(pastFileToFind.cloneNode(false),true);
```

since later on when i was trying to add the newWarningRoot to newFileRoot, they had different Documents (newWarningRoot was correct but newFileRoot was connected to the wrong document)