# Issue with Open JDK 11 and JAXP

Tags: java

I am trying to migrate from JDK 1.8 to Open JDK 11 and when i try to make webservice calls, i am getting below error -

```
org.w3c.dom.DOMException: WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR: A node is used in a different document than the one that created it.
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ParentNode.internalInsertBefore(ParentNode.java:356)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ParentNode.insertBefore(ParentNode.java:287)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.NodeImpl.appendChild(NodeImpl.java:237)
    at org.apache.wss4j.dom.util.WSSecurityUtil.prependChildElement(WSSecurityUtil.java:314)
    at org.apache.wss4j.dom.util.WSSecurityUtil.findWsseSecurityHeaderBlock(WSSecurityUtil.java:435)
    at org.apache.wss4j.dom.message.WSSecHeader.insertSecurityHeader(WSSecHeader.java:165)
    at org.apache.wss4j.dom.handler.WSHandler.doSenderAction(WSHandler.java:117)
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j2.Wss4jHandler.doSenderAction(Wss4jHandler.java:63)
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j2.Wss4jSecurityInterceptor.secureMessage(Wss4jSecurityInterceptor.java:574)
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.security.AbstractWsSecurityInterceptor.handleRequest(AbstractWsSecurityInterceptor.java:210)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:597)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:555)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:390)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:383)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:373)
    at com.aa.apt.cbs.invent.webservice.service.MishandledBagsServiceClient.getForwardedBags(MishandledBagsServiceClient.java:76)
    at com.aa.apt.cbs.invent.quartz.job.MishandledBagProcessorHelper.callMishandleForwardBagService(MishandledBagProcessorHelper.java:46)
    at com.aa.apt.cbs.invent.quartz.job.MishandledBagProcessorJob.execute(MishandledBagProcessorJob.java:24)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
```

Comment: Check `MishandledBagsServiceClient.getForwardedBags`, make sure you're not adding nodes to a document that isn't the owner of those nodes. (check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/873247/how-do-i-copy-dom-nodes-from-one-document-to-another-in-java/873604)). Not sure if this problem is expected from a JDK1.8>OpenJDK11 migration, that seems weird

Comment: Any sollutions? I'm getting the same error while securing SOAP Message.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem with jdk 11 and jax-ws webservice calls

Possible solutions:

[Too high version of saaj-impl (1.4.x or higher)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56633929) - heled me

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj</groupId>
    <artifactId>saaj-impl</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.28</version>
</dependency>
```

Bug with [wss4j-ws-security-dom library in version 2.2.0](https://better-coding.com/solved-org-w3c-dom-domexception-wrong_document_err/) - didn't affect in my case