# How do I append an XML request to the only SOAPElement child of the SOAP Body?

Tags: java, xml, soap

### The use case

I need to contact an external SOAP service in a programmatic way. To do so, I need to create a SOAP request which looks like the below:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:pric="http://myURI/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <pric:myAPI>
        <XmlDocument>
            <OtherXmlContent>
            </OtherXmlContent>
        </XmlDocument>
      </pric:myAPI>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

### The task I'm blocked on

I manage  to create the following SOAP envelope:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:pric="http://myURI/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <pric:myAPI>

      </pric:myAPI>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

What I need to do, provided an input, is to add the XML request:

```
<XmlDocument>
    <OtherXmlContent>
    </OtherXmlContent>
</XmlDocument>
```

... as a child of `<pric:myAPI>`, which is the only child of my `<soapenv:Body>`.

For information, the above Soap envelope (without `XmlDocument` yet) is created by the following code:

```
MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();
SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration(pricingNamespace, pricingNamespaceURI);
SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();
SOAPElement pricingWrapper = soapBody.addChildElement(pricingAction, pricingNamespace);
```

... hence, what I need to do is to append a child to `pricingWrapper`. I choose how I create this child, I have full control on the function generating it which is this one:

```
private static String createXmlProductFromDealingDocument(Document dealings)
```

### Attempt 1 - adding the document as text

I have tried to add the `XmlDocument` as text of `pricingWrapper`. 
This is how I did it:

```
pricingWrapper.addTextNode(createXmlProductFromDealingDocument(dealingFile));
```

The problem, though, is that all the characters `<` and `>` of the `XmlDocument` rendered as `String` are escaped by the method `addTextNode`. In other words, I can see my body has the correct content, but `<` is replaced with `&lt;` and `>` is replaced with `&gt;`, so making the SOAP request invalid for the target service.

### Attempt 2 - adding the document as child node

Another attempt I did was to return a `Node` instead of a `String` from my function:

```
private static Node createXmlProductFromDealingDocument(Document dealings)
```

and append this `Node` as a child of `pricingWrapper`:

```
pricingWrapper.appendChild(createXmlProductFromDealingDocument(dealingFile));
```

The above raises an exception of type:

> org.w3c.dom.DOMException: WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR: A node is used in a different document than the one that created it.

Ok, fair enough. I posted a question (deleted shortly as I wanted to go deeper in my researches) yesterday, and a user kindly suggested me in a comment to check how to clone DOM nodes by referencing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/873247/how-do-i-copy-dom-nodes-from-one-document-to-another-in-java).

I tried to do so as follows:

```
Node pricingRequest = createXmlProductFromDealingDocument(dealingFile);
Node soapPricingRequest = pricingRequest.cloneNode(true);
pricingWrapper.getOwnerDocument().adoptNode(soapPricingRequest);
pricingWrapper.appendChild(soapPricingRequest);
```

However, this raises a new exception:

> org.w3c.dom.DOMException: NOT_SUPPORTED_ERR: The implementation does not support the requested type of object or operation.

... on the following line:

```
pricingWrapper.getOwnerDocument().adoptNode(soapPricingRequest);
```

... and I really don't see how else I could append the child differently than what I did above.

### What is my question

I just would like to complete my SOAP request the right way. I do not have any preference whether this would be done by injecting the XML as text or as a `Node`, as far as is the proper way and especially as far as it works :)
Could anyone please tip me how could I fix my above issues?

Comment: @GPI it worked, brilliant! Please write your comment as an answer so I can upvote, accept and give you your well deserved reputation :)

Comment: Done. Very nice, detailed question with lots of background. +1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the javadoc of adoptNode() :

> DOMException - NOT_SUPPORTED_ERR: Raised if the source node is of type DOCUMENT, DOCUMENT_TYPE. ".

So, you could you chek if `soapPrincingRequest` is indeed a `DOCUMENT` type of node (using `getNodeType()`) ?

If so, I would advise you to cast `soapPrincingRequest` as a `Document`, then access its root `NODE` with `getDocumentElement()`, and try to `adopt()` this `NODE`, and not the `DOCUMENT` one.

XML APIs, when they strive for correctness are always a bit touchy to use, and the distinction between a `Document` and its `root element` actually matter. So it's a bit of a pain, but we get there in the end.

Comment: apparently your solution was good, but only when running by unit test! I've posted a new question, if you wanna have a look is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54812153/adoptnode-appendchild-works-from-unittest-but-not-from-real-code-executio).:)

Comment: Question deleted, in the end I needed just to use `importNode()` instead of `adoptNode()`. Like that, both unit test and real RMI call will work :)

Comment: It's probably because you had 1) `clone()`, then 2) `getDocumentElement`, 3) `adoptNode()`, which meant that the object that was adopted was not the cloned-one. By using `import` instead of `adopt`, you mitigated this issue because import is basically clone+adopt. If you had reversed step 1 and 2 above, I guess you would have been fine.